# Checking if template literals are available in script

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find a way to check if **template-literals** in JS are supported in the given browser. The idea is to pass them different scripts created by *Babel* if the browser doesn't support *ES6* features. So I'm trying:

```
function check_es6() {
    try { `foo` }
    catch (e) { return false; }

    return true;
}

alert(check_es6());
```

However, on my old iPhone I get:

> Invalid character On line 141 of
>   https://m.xxx.org/2018/js/app.js on 1 page.
>
> Seen in Mobile Safari 7. Last seen 20 minutes ago. Occurred once so far. Occurred before page load.

Line 141 is:

```
try { `foo` }
```

Is there a better way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so managed to work it out myself :)

```
try { eval("`foo`"); }
```

This correctly shows "false" now when the browser doesn't support template literals, and "true" in later browsers that do.